# AngularJS 1.5 websocket library installation problem

Tags: angularjs, websocket, installation

I have installed the following library 
https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket

in my AngularJS 1.5 application. When i go to run I get the following

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined
at angular-websocket.js:46
at angular-websocket.js:10
at angular-websocket.js:13
```

Line 46:   var noop = _angular2.default.noop;

Any ideas

Comment: Can you show us how do you use it? - we need some code to see why do you have that error

Comment: I also use that library. I don't have any error